# beej guide pipe example explanation

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

The following code is the pipe implementation given in beej's guide:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
 int pfds[2];
 pipe(pfds);
 if (!fork()) {
 close(1); /* close normal stdout */
 dup(pfds[1]); /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
 close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
 execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
 } else {
 close(0); /* close normal stdin */
 dup(pfds[0]); /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
 close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
 execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I wanted to ask:

1. Is it possible that `close(0)` is executed before `dup(pfds[1])`? If yes, then in that case the program will not behave as expected.
2. What is the use of the following lines of code:

   ```
   close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
   close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
   ```

And what would change if these lines were not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that close(0) is executed before dup(pfds[1])? If yes,
>   then in that case the program will not behave as expected.

Yes, it is possible to have the parent successfully complete `close(0)` before the child calls `dup(pfds[1])`. However, this is not a problem. When you fork a new process, the new process gets an entire copy of the parent's memory address space, including open file descriptors (except those marked with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag - see `fcntl(2)`). So, essentially each process has its own private copy of the file descriptors and is isolated and free to do whatever it wants with that copy.

Thus, when the parent calls `close(0)`, it is only closing its copy of file descriptor 0 (`stdin`); it does not affect the child in any way, which still has a reference to `stdin` and can use it if needed (even though in this example it won't).

> What is the use of the following lines of code:

```
close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
```

Best practices mandate that you should close file descriptors that you don't use - this is the case for `close(pfds[0])`. Unused open file descriptors eat up space and resources, why keep it open if you're not going to use it?

`close(pfds[1])` is a little more subtle though. Pipes report end of file only when there is no more data in the pipe buffer *and* there are no active writers, i.e., no live processes that have the pipe open for writing. If you do not close `pfds[1]` in the parent, the program will hang forever because `wc(1)` will never see the end of input, since there is a process (`wc(1)` itself) that has the pipe opened for writing and as such could (but won't) write more data.

Tl;DR: `close(pfds[0])` is just good practice but not mandatory; `close(pfds[1])` is absolutely necessary to ensure program correctness.

Answer (score -1):

Question 1:
Yes it is entirely possible that "close(0);" (in the parent) is executed before "dup(pfds[1]);" (in the child). But since this happens in different processes, the child will still have fd 0 open.

Question 2:
It is good bookkeeping practice to close the end of the pipe that a process is not going to use. That way, you can avoid bugs further down the road in more complex programs. In the above scenario, the child process should ever only read from the pipe. If you close the write end in the child, eny attempt to write to it will cause an error, otherwise you might have a bug that is hard to detect.

Comment: How child will still have fd 0 open? file descriptor shared across process , and dup() take lowest available FD. I am not able to understand.

Comment: fd 0 is shared through the fork() call. But after that, each process has its own memory and resources. So the parent can close fd 0, and then it is free to be used by the dup() call. This does nothing to fd 0 in the child, which still points to stdin.

Comment: Question 2 is not really about good bookkeeping practices, there's much more to it than that. Try removing `close(pfds[1])` and you're left with a hanging program. [Hint: pipes do not report EOF when there is at least a writer]